# I have a double light switch in my living-room that I want to cancel out for the time being

Tags: electrical, switch

How would I wire the wires together to keep power on throughout my house?

When it is disconnected I don't have power to my kitchen light, my hall light, my living room, nor back bath or bedroom.

Inside the box where the switches go there are 2 sets of wires coming through the top and 2 sets coming through the bottom, so a total of 4 black 4 white and 4 ground. How do I need to wire the circuit to keep power on without installing new switches?

Comment: When you say "cancel out" do you mean to leave the lights always on or always off? When you say "double light switch" do you mean two switches controlling two lights?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box, showing the backs of the switches? How about a diagram showing which wires go to which switches?

Comment: Keeping the light always on. When i say double light switch i mean double that controls two different lights, one for the living room, the other is the outside light.

Answer (score 1):

Always turn off the power at the service panel before working on any house wiring.

The particular method depends on how the switches are wired.

If each switch has three wires (including the ground) connected to it, then the solution is very easy. For each switch: leave the ground wire connected, disconnect the other two wires from the switch terminals, straighten the ends, twist them together, and screw a wire nut onto the ends.

If any switch has more than three wires (including the ground) connected to it, then you need to make a diagram or photo to get help deciding which wires to twist together.

Comment: Repeatedly bending copper wires can lead to higher resistance and /or breakage.  It's better to simply clip off the loops bent in the wire, and start fresh.

Comment: There is one light switch hooked up in the box. I want to remove the one light switch,Then put on a blank cover. I dont want to use it temporarily. i  dont have power in my living room light, bathroom light, bedroom light, hallway light, kitchen light. I need to complete the circuit again and dont kno which wires come in and go back to the box